# pgadmin black background font on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, pgadmin

I just installed pgadmin3 on my Debian CrunchBang distro and the fonts inside looks with black background. I don't know how to fix it, I have default theme on everything.

I don't know if I can post this problem here, if I can't... sorry.

[image: img]

Comment: I have the exact opposite; white on dark background.

Answer (score 0):

this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505168/pgadmin-show-object-browser-text-white-on-white-with-dark-theme) resolves issue.

You need to change color in server properties (in object browser window).

Answer (score 0):

disconnect server then right click and open properties you will see you have an option to change colour